# Consulta LINQ, Group by con Group Join

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

Tengo esta consulta en Transact-SQL

```
SELECT t_productospreguntas.d_pregunta,
t_productos.d_titulo,
t_productosimagenes.d_archivo,
t_productosrespuestas.d_respuesta
FROM t_productospreguntas
INNER JOIN t_productos
ON t_productospreguntas.c_usuario = t_productos.c_usuario
AND t_productospreguntas.c_empresa = t_productos.c_empresa
AND t_productospreguntas.c_producto = t_productos.c_producto
LEFT OUTER JOIN  t_productosimagenes
ON t_productos.c_usuario = t_productosimagenes.c_usuario
AND t_productos.c_empresa = t_productosimagenes.c_empresa
AND t_productos.c_producto = t_productosimagenes.c_producto
AND t_productos.c_consec = t_productosimagenes.c_consec
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_productosrespuestas
ON t_productospreguntas.c_usuario = t_productosrespuestas.c_usuario
AND t_productospreguntas.c_empresa = t_productosrespuestas.c_empresa
AND t_productospreguntas.c_producto = t_productosrespuestas.c_producto
AND t_productospreguntas.c_consecpregunta = t_productosrespuestas.c_consecpregunta
WHERE t_productospreguntas.c_usuario = 1
AND t_productospreguntas.c_empresa = 1 
AND t_productospreguntas.c_producto = 1 
AND t_productos.c_status <> 3 
AND t_productosimagenes.c_imagen = 1
AND t_productosimagenes.c_tamaño = 4
```

He tratado de realizarlo con la siguiente consulta en linq pero no me da el resultado esperado.

```vbnet
From u In db.t_productospreguntas
Group Join v In db.t_productosrespuestas
On u.c_usuario Equals v.c_usuario And
u.c_empresa Equals v.c_empresa And
u.c_producto Equals v.c_producto And
u.c_consecpregunta Equals v.c_consecpregunta
Into uv = Group
From v In uv.DefaultIfEmpty
Join w In db.t_productos
On u.c_usuario Equals w.c_usuario And
u.c_empresa Equals w.c_empresa And
u.c_producto Equals w.c_producto
Group Join x In db.t_productosimagenes
On w.c_usuario Equals x.c_usuario And
w.c_empresa Equals x.c_empresa And
w.c_producto Equals x.c_producto And
w.c_consec Equals x.c_consec
Into wx = Group
From x In wx.DefaultIfEmpty
Where u.c_usuario = piUsuario And
u.c_empresa = piEmpresa And
u.c_producto = piProducto And
w.c_status <> enumEstatus.iRECONFIGURADO And
x.c_imagen = 1 And
x.c_tamaño = enumImgTamaños.i160x160
Group v.d_respuesta
By u.d_pregunta, w.d_titulo, x.d_archivo
Into g = Group
Select d_pregunta, d_titulo, d_archivo, g
```

Ojala me pudieran orientar, ya que se realizar consultas en SQL pero soy nuevo con linq.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. El problema con tu pregunta es que es una consulta sql muy compleja para analizar, y más sin tener las tablas para poder comprobarlo. Yo te recomendaría simplificar la consulta, dividirla en partes lo mas sencillas posibles e ir construyendola poco a poco.

Comment: Si tienes dudas en cuanto a como hacer un inner join o un left outer join en LINQ, simplemente buscando en Google "left outer join LINQ" por ejemplo verás la manera de hacerlo. Suerte y si tienes alguna duda mas concreta, no dudes en realizar una nueva pregunta y trataremos de ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracia por los comentarios, he realizado búsquedas en google, pero son consultas de ejemplo muy comunes, no encuentro un ejemplo como el mio. En resumen el problema surge al realizar un Group Join en conjunto con group by.

Agradesco tu ayuda. Saludos.